# Single R script on multiple nodes

Tags: r, unix, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I would like to utilize CPU cores from multiple nodes to execute a single R script. Each node contains 16 cores and are assigned to me via a Slurm tool.

So far my code looks like the following:

```
ncores <- 16

List_1 <- list(...)
List_2 <- list(...)

cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
getDoParWorkers()

foreach(L_1=List_1) %:% 
foreach(L_2=List_2) %dopar% {
...
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

I execute it via the following command in a UNIX shell:

```
mpirun -np 1 R --no-save < file_path_R_script.R > another_file_path.Rout
```

That works fine on a single node. However, I have not figured out whether it is sufficient to increase ncores to 32 once I have access to a second node. Does R include the additional 16 cores on the other node automatically? Or do I have to make use of another R package?

Comment: You can tell `mpirun` to consider other hosts. It is part of your local MPI setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mpirun` to launch an R script does not make sense without using [Rmpi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpi/index.html).

Looking at your code, you might do want you want to do without MPI. The recipe would be as follows to use 2x16 cores.

Ask for 2 tasks and 16 cpus per task

```
#SBATCH --nodes 2
#SBATCH --ntasks 2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 16
```

Start your program with Slurm's [srun](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html) command

```
srun R --no-save < file_path_R_script.R > another_file_path.Rout
```

The `srun` command will start 2 instances of the R script on two distinct nodes and will setup an environment variable `SLURM_PROCID` to be 0 on one node and 1 on the other

Use the value of `SLURM_PROCID` in your Rscript to split the work among the two processes started by `srun`

```
ncores <- 16

taskID <- as.numeric(Sys.getenv('SLURM_PROCID'))

List_1 <- list(...)
List_2 <- list(...)

cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
getDoParWorkers()

Lits_1 <- split(List_1, 1:2)[[taskID+1]] # Split work based on value of SLURM_PROCID

foreach(L_1=List_1) %:% 
foreach(L_2=List_2) %dopar% {
...
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

You will need to save the result on disk and then merge the partial results into a single full result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I modified the srun line a bit, i.e. to `srun --nodes=2 --ntasks=2 --cpus-per-task=16 R --no-save < file_path_R_script.R > another_file_path.Rout` . Otherwise the system requested a single node only.
If I increase the number of nodes to 5, I do not need to modify `[[taskID+1]]` , right? Just change `--node=2` to `--nodes=5` , `ntasks=2` to `ntasks=5` and `split(List_1, 1:2)` to `split(List_1, 1:5)` ?

Comment: I did not test, but yes, that is the idea.