# slrum runnig one job across multiple nodes

Tags: r, future, slurm

I have an R script that use parallel computing via the parallel and future packages. The code to set the parallel configuration in the R script is:

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(100)
future::plan(cluster, workers=cl)
```

I am running the R script in HPC where each node have 20 CPU. What is SLRUM configuration to run the R script as one job across multiple nodes. will:

```
--cpus-per-task=100
```

be sufficient?
Thank you

Comment: #SBATCH --ntasks 100, should be enough?

Answer (score 2):

By default, if you request `N` nodes and launch `M` tasks, the slurm will distribute the M tasks in N nodes. So, if you want to launch 100 tasks across 2 Nodes, you just need to specify `--nodes 2` and `--ntasks 100`. The 100 tasks (100 times your R script will be launched) will be spread across 2 Nodes.

But, if you only want to launch your R script twice (one per each node to utilize shared memory and inside each node allocate 20 cpus for that single task) then you can do, `--nodes 2` `--ntasks 2` `--cpus-per-task 20`.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905099/slurm-use-cores-from-multiple-nodes-for-r-parallelization?rq=1), I realized that I can not run my job on multiple nodes since they do not share memory.